# Did Charlemagne ever visit Constantinople?

Tags: middle-ages, architecture

The answer to this question, is probably no.  There doesn't appear to be any significant historical evidence pointing to Charlemagne traveling beyond Italy. However, there is *perhaps* one exception......The Aachen Palace-Cathedral.

It is well known within historical circles that Charlemagne was very impressed with the Saint Sophia Cathedral in Constantinople. He was so impressed with the Saint Sophia's architecture that he commissioned his Palace-Cathedral in Aachen to be designed in the Byzantine style-(namely the Cathedral's interior).

Now it is likely the case that Charlemagne's Architect(s) may have been the ones who visited the Saint Sophia Cathedral in Constantinople and wrote blueprints for the architectural style of the Aachen Palace-Cathedral. But, then again, perhaps Charlemagne himself visited Constantinople on a rare State or Diplomatic visit and viewed the Saint Sophia Cathedral with his own eyes.

Again, it seems unlikely that Charlemagne traveled beyond Italy; however there may be some available historical evidence which would contradict such a traditionally held position.

Comment: If there's "some available historical evidence" otherwise, then it wouldn't *be* an accepted historical fact that Charlemagne never went to the East.

Comment: He also definitely traveled beyond Italy, like to Saxony, Pannonia, and Hispania.

Comment: What I meant by, "traveling beyond Italy", was as to whether or not Charlemagne traveled to the East.  Perhaps I should have said, "traveled to the East of Italy".

Comment: [Einhard's life of Charlemagne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vita_Karoli_Magni) gives pretty detailed information about C's travels, and mentions no trip to Constantinople.

Comment: hate to be a nitpick but even to the east of Italy is Pannonia.  He spend a decent amount of time fighting the Slavs there.

Answer (score 6):

We don't have to look as far as Constantinople for the inspiration of the [Aachen Palace Cathedral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatine_Chapel,_Aachen), or theorize about unknown trips to the east for Charlemagne. A building we *know* was visited by Charlemagne is considered to be the source of much of the [structural design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatine_Chapel,_Aachen#Structure) style:

> The plan and decoration owe much to the sixth-century Basilica of San
>   Vitale, Ravenna. Indeed, Charlemagne visited Ravenna three times, the
>   first in 787. In that year he wrote to Pope Hadrian I and requested
>   "mosaic, marbles, and other materials from floors and walls" in Rome
>   and Ravenna, for his palace.

So we can associate directly the visit to Ravenna with the start of the construction project. No trip to Constantinople involved.The [Basilica of San Vitale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basilica_of_San_Vitale) is also of Byzantine styling(emphasis mine):

> The church is most famous for its wealth of Byzantine mosaics, the
>   largest and best preserved *outside of Constantinople*.

Clearly, Charlemagne liked the Byzantine design, but he did not have to go all the way to Constantinople to observe it.

Comment: Very good point; Admittedly, I completely forgot about the San Vitale Cathedral in Ravenna.  It makes perfect historical sense.  Afterall, Ravenna, was, in a way, "The Byzantium of the West".

Comment: And it makes perfect sense from an architectural standpoint.  If my memory  is correct, the exteriors of both the San Vitale and Aachen Cathedrals are very similar looking.